# HTML Canvas - Draw Shape after Interval

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval

The script below draws 4 curved rectangles with images in them. It draws them all at once despite using a `setInterval` of `2500` milliseconds before calling the function that draws them. I would like the first rectangle (i.e. top-left) to be drawn immediately, and then the other rectangles to be drawn after that one (with one being drawn every 2.5 seconds). Why does this function not do this and how can it be done? Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

var images = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXmPa.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGhCL.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5xu4.png', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6BO0.jpg']

var curvedRect = function(id, selectionnum, x, y, w, h) {
  this.id = id;
  this.selectionnum = selectionnum;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
}

curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect = function() {
  var img=new Image();
  img.src=images[this.selectionnum];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth='8';
  ctx.strokeStyle='white';
  ctx.moveTo(this.x+10, this.y);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.w-10, this.y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x+this.w, this.y, this.x+this.w, this.y+10);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.w, this.y+this.h-10);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x+this.w, this.y+this.h, this.x+this.w-10, this.y+this.h);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x+10, this.y+this.h);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x, this.y+this.h, this.x, this.y+this.h-10);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y+10);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x, this.y, this.x+10, this.y);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.drawImage(img, this.x+2.5, this.y+2.5, this.w-5, this.h-5);
}

var Paint = function(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
  this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.element.width, this.element.height);

  for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
    try {
      setInterval(this.shapes[i].makeCurvedRect(), 2500);
    }
    catch(err) {}
  }
}

var paint = new Paint(c);
var img1 = new curvedRect(1, 0, 200, 55, 150, 150);
var img2 = new curvedRect(2, 1, 375, 55, 150, 150);
var img3 = new curvedRect(3, 2, 200, 230, 150, 150);
var img4 = new curvedRect(4, 3, 375, 230, 150, 150);

paint.addShape(img1);
paint.addShape(img2);
paint.addShape(img3);
paint.addShape(img4);

paint.render();
```

```css
canvas {
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='game.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "750" height = "500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
setInterval(this.shapes[i].makeCurvedRect(), 2500);
```

which executes `makeCurvedRect()` immediately and supplies `setInterval()` with the return value with a bound function

```
setTimeout(curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect.bind(this.shapes[i]), 2500 * i);
```

or a fat arrow function

```
setTimeout(() => this.shapes[i].makeCurvedRect(), 2500 * i);
```

where the delay increases by 2500 for each rectangle.